# Use input file in Jenkins Active Choices Reactive References plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I'm trying to implement a pipeline in which, depending on the choice of parameter, the user sees either text input or file input.
I use Active Choices Parameter:
First:
[First Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3oLO.png)
Second:
[First Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEVAz.png)
then i need to get this values in pipeline code
for example:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Demo Active Choices Parameter') {
      steps {
        echo "${services}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with text input - it works
how can i get the file in pipeline?
thank you and sorry for english.

Comment: #1 I'm not sure if you can add fields with html in jenkins.

Comment: With the text input it works, but i can't do the same with the file input(

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved with use this html input:

```
<input name='file' type='file' jsonaware='true'>
```

And in pipeline i use this library for jenkins: https://github.com/janvrany/jenkinsci-unstashParam-library

```
@Library("jenkinsci-unstashParam-library") _
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (object == 'variable') {
                        sh "echo ${input}"
                        //SOMETHING ELSE
                    }
                    else if (object == 'file') {
                        def input_file = unstashParam "input"
                        sh "cat ${input_file}"
                        //SOMETHING ELSE
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```